# More specific javafx data validation

Tags: java, validation, javafx

I am trying to implement data validation for my program:

```
private boolean typeVal (TextField typeInput, String typeMessage){
    try {
        String type = (typeInput.getText());
        addButtonClicked();
        return true;
    }catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        AlertBox.display("Datatype Error", "Please check all fields are entered and are using correct datatypes");
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is one example of the validators that I am trying to create, the problem comes when someone enters a string of numbers. Is there anyway to make this more specific to just certain characters?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard validator in JavaFX. But there is several JavaFX libraries that provide such functionality, and none of them contains simple password validator. So I had to implement validators by [myself](https://github.com/kokorin/Studiorum/tree/bf33082e408c9e72105eec5bc629be8b4a14ce02/client/src/java/studiorum/validator).

Your code isn't quite good. You add click listener in some function. You should rather add listeners in `initialize()` function of FXML controller. And also you should disable button when text is empty:

```
button.disableProperty().bind(textField.textProperty().isEmpty());
```

Comment: There is [TextFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html), but currently it behaves like Swing's [COMMIT_OR_REVERT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html#COMMIT_OR_REVERT):  Invalid input is silently discarded and the last good value is restored.

Comment: Your link is broken, did you move your repository?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have updated my answer with correct link. I just did some refactoring and broke the original link.